# Parsing text file to data frame in python

Tags: python, parsing

I am new to parsing in python . I want to parse the following type of text

value one = 5

value two = 10

%some text here

value three = 15

%some text

value one = 12

value two = 13

%some text here

value three = 11
.. and this goes on 
I want to extract .value one. .value two. and .value three. and arrange them in a tabular format for processing. Any ideas on how to do it

I tried the following till now. It gives me error: local value value two referenced before assignment

```
import re
import pandas as pd
val_dict = { 'value_one':re.compile(r'value one = (?P<value_one>.*)\n'),
           'value_two':re.compile(r'value two = (?P<value_two>.*)\n'),
           'value_three':re.compile(r'value three = (?P<value_three>.*)\n')}

def _parse_line(line):


    for key, val in val_dict.items():
        match = val.search(line)
        if match:
            return key, match
# if there are no matches
    return None, None


def parse_file(filepath):


    data = []  
    with open(filepath, 'r') as file_object:
        line = file_object.readline()
        while line:

            key, match = _parse_line(line)

            if key == 'value_one':
                value_one = match.group('value_one')
                value_one = int(value_one)

            if key == 'value_two':
                value_two = match.group('value_two')
                value_two = int(value_two)

            if key == 'value_three':
                value_three = match.group('value_three')
                value_three = int(value_three)

            row = {
                        'value one': value_one,
                        'value two': value_two,
                        'value three': value_three 
                    }
                # append the dictionary to the data list
            data.append(row)
            line = file_object.readline()


        data = pd.DataFrame(data)

        data.set_index(['value one', 'value two', 'value three'], inplace=True)

        data = data.groupby(level=data.index.names).first()

        data = data.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')
        return data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    filepath = 'test3.txt'
    data = parse_file(filepath)
```

Comment: What was your implementation from your research?

Comment: What have you tried till now? And also whats the expected output ?

Comment: Is it a complete example. How are you calling `_parse_line` and how you are managing the `dicts` returned by the same

Comment: Do your comment lines always start with a percent sign?

Comment: apologies first time user, the whole code is pasted above.

Comment: @jeschwar as already mentioned the first few lines are part of a text file(not any programming code). I used % sign for irrelevant data in the text file.

Comment: Congrats (err...) for your first question! As others commented, this site has rules for the questions, and as a new user, reading [ask] is really a must do. But with your current code, the question is now much better :-)

Comment: Can we assume that the file will always have 3 lines value one, value two, value three in that order, or can it contain partial sequences (only 2 values) or sequences out of order (two, one three).

Comment: yes it will be always in that order

Comment: i am opening another post with the same text modified

Comment: here is the link to the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56280513/parsing-text-file-to-tabular-data-for-processing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem comes that on one line, you can only have one of `'value one'`, `'value two'` or `'value_three'`, so on first line only variable `value_one` will be defined, but you try to use all three hence the error.

You should only append a row when you have a *full sequence*. You could try to change your code to:

```
def parse_file(filepath):
    data = []  
    with open(filepath, 'r') as file_object:
        row = {}                                # prepare an empty row
        for line in file_object:
            key, match = _parse_line(line)
            # search for keys in the line
            if key == 'value_one':
                value_one = match.group('value_one')
                value_one = int(value_one)
                if 'value one' in row:          # we always have a full row
                    data.append(row)            # append it to the data liest
                    row = {}                    # and reset it
                row['value one'] = value_one    # we have a match: store the value in row

            if key == 'value_two':
                value_two = match.group('value_two')
                value_two = int(value_two)
                if 'value two' in row:
                    data.append(row)
                    row = {}
                row['value two'] = value_two

            if key == 'value_three':
                value_three = match.group('value_three')
                value_three = int(value_three)
                if 'value three' in row:
                    data.append(row)
                    row = {}
                row['value three'] = value_three

        if row != {}:                      # do not forget the last row
            data.append(row)
        data = pd.DataFrame(data)
        return data
```

I have also removed the last part as IMHO it is no longer a matter of parsing a text file to build a dataframe but is just pandas dataframe processing.

Comment: what changes will i have to do probabily if i encounter a different ordering say value one value two value three value three value one value two value three

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

with open('text.txt') as fd:
    data = fd.read()

val_to_pattern = {
    'value_one': r'value one = (\d+)',
    'value_two': r'value two = (\d+)',
    'value_three': r'value three = (\d+)',
}

val_dict = {}
for key, patt in val_to_pattern.items():
    val_dict[key] = re.findall(patt, data)

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(val_dict)
print(df)
```

The result:

```
  value_one value_two value_three
0         5        10          15
1        12        13          11
```