# Parsing text file to tabular data for processing

Tags: python, regex, string, parsing, split

The problem at hand is to parse a particular data in a tabular form using python.A small part of data is shown below

```
Statistics indicator:0x222235

number of records = 3 

records[0]

value one = 2

value two = 5

blocks = 2

block[0] {

some irrelevant data....

value three = 4 bytes

}

block[1]{

some irrelevant data...

value three = 6 bytes

}

records[1]

value one = 3

value two = 5

blocks = 1

block[0] {

some irrelevant data....

value three = 4 bytes

}

records[2]

value one = 7

value two = 6

blocks = 2

block[0] {

some irrelevant data....

value three = 3 bytes

}

block[1]{

some irrelevant data...

value three = 4 bytes

}

Statistics indicator:0x135256

number of records = 2 

records[0]

value one = 4

value two = 8

blocks = 1

block[0] {

some irrelevant data....

value three = 6 bytes

}

records[1]

value one = 3

value two = 5

blocks = 1

block[0] {

some irrelevant data....

value three = 3 bytes

}
```

As shown , the data has a particular pattern. It has statistics indicator at the start of every particular block of data.It has the number of records field to indicate the number of records the data block has.Within each record the 'value one' and value two' is distinct. However there are several "value three"'s depending on the number of blocks each record has which is indicated by 'blocks'field.
The problem here is to arrange the following data in the tabular form adding all the value three's corresponding to the particular record.

The final table should look something like this:

value one value two value three

```
2          5        10 

3          5         4

7          6         7

4          8         6

3          5         3
```

The approach I am thinking is to first find 'Statistics indicator'
If I find 'Statistics indicator' I will look for number of records and blocks corresponding to each record to iterate through the blocks and sum value three's corresponding to similar value one and value two.

Here is the code which I tried to extract value one value two and value three. I have not delved into summing value three's yet.

```
import re
import pandas as pd
val_dict = { 'value_one':re.compile(r'value one = (?P<value_one>.*)\n'),
           'value_two':re.compile(r'value two = (?P<value_two>.*)\n'),
           'value_three':re.compile(r'value three = (?P<value_three>.*)\n')}

def _parse_line(line):


    for key, val in val_dict.items():
        match = val.search(line)
        if match:
            return key, match
# if there are no matches
    return None, None


def parse_file(filepath):
    data = []  
    with open(filepath, 'r') as file_object:
        row = {}                                # prepare an empty row
        for line in file_object:
            key, match = _parse_line(line)
            # search for keys in the line
            if key == 'value_one':
                value_one = match.group('value_one')
                value_one = int(value_one)
                if 'value one' in row:          # we always have a full row
                    data.append(row)            # append it to the data liest
                    row = {}                    # and reset it
                row['value one'] = value_one    # we have a match: store the value in row

            if key == 'value_two':
                value_two = match.group('value_two')
                value_two = int(value_two)
                if 'value two' in row:
                    data.append(row)
                    row = {}
                row['value two'] = value_two

            if key == 'value_three':
                value_three = match.group('value_three')
                value_three = int(value_three)
                if 'value three' in row:
                    data.append(row)
                    row = {}
                row['value three'] = value_three

        if row != {}:                      # do not forget the last row
            data.append(row)
        data = pd.DataFrame(data)
        return data
if __name__ == '__main__':
    filepath = 'test3.txt'
    data = parse_file(filepath)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, maybe we don't want to use regular expressions. However, if we might want to do so, we can set attribute names as a left boundary, and collect our desired digits, maybe with an expression similar to:

```
value\s+(one|two|three)\s+=\s+([0-9]+)
```

Then, the rest of our problem can be scripted. We can also add more boundaries to our expressions, if that'd be necessary.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QELFMp/1/)

#### Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"value\s+(one|two|three)\s+=\s+([0-9]+)"

test_str = ("Statistics indicator:0x222235\n\n"
    "number of records = 3\n\n"
    "records[0]\n\n"
    "value one = 2\n\n"
    "value two = 5\n\n"
    "blocks = 2\n\n"
    "block[0] {\n\n"
    "some irrelevant data....\n\n"
    "value three = 4 bytes\n\n"
    "}\n\n"
    "block[1]{\n\n"
    "some irrelevant data...\n\n"
    "value three = 6 bytes\n\n"
    "}\n\n"
    "records[1]\n\n"
    "value one = 3\n\n"
    "value two = 5\n\n"
    "blocks = 1\n\n"
    "block[0] {\n\n"
    "some irrelevant data....\n\n"
    "value three = 4 bytes\n\n"
    "}\n\n"
    "records[2]\n\n"
    "value one = 7\n\n"
    "value two = 6\n\n"
    "blocks = 2\n\n"
    "block[0] {\n\n"
    "some irrelevant data....\n\n"
    "value three = 3 bytes\n\n"
    "}\n\n"
    "block[1]{\n\n"
    "some irrelevant data...\n\n"
    "value three = 4 bytes\n\n"
    "}\n\n"
    "Statistics indicator:0x135256\n\n"
    "number of records = 2\n\n"
    "records[0]\n\n"
    "value one = 4\n\n"
    "value two = 8\n\n"
    "blocks = 1\n\n"
    "block[0] {\n\n"
    "some irrelevant data....\n\n"
    "value three = 6 bytes\n\n"
    "}\n\n"
    "records[1]\n\n"
    "value one = 3\n\n"
    "value two = 5\n\n"
    "blocks = 1\n\n"
    "block[0] {\n\n"
    "some irrelevant data....\n\n"
    "value three = 3 bytes\n\n"
    "}")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

#### Demo

```js
const regex = /value\s+(one|two|three)\s+=\s+([0-9]+)/gm;
const str = `Statistics indicator:0x222235

number of records = 3

records[0]

value one = 2

value two = 5

blocks = 2

block[0] {

some irrelevant data....

value three = 4 bytes

}

block[1]{

some irrelevant data...

value three = 6 bytes

}

records[1]

value one = 3

value two = 5

blocks = 1

block[0] {

some irrelevant data....

value three = 4 bytes

}

records[2]

value one = 7

value two = 6

blocks = 2

block[0] {

some irrelevant data....

value three = 3 bytes

}

block[1]{

some irrelevant data...

value three = 4 bytes

}

Statistics indicator:0x135256

number of records = 2

records[0]

value one = 4

value two = 8

blocks = 1

block[0] {

some irrelevant data....

value three = 6 bytes

}

records[1]

value one = 3

value two = 5

blocks = 1

block[0] {

some irrelevant data....

value three = 3 bytes

}`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired, it can be modified or changed in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/DhITMG/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]